# How can I link a CSS file with my pages inside a folder.Html/css?

Tags: css, html

I am doing a project which is building a website for my CS 205 class. I have made it using [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) for the HTML files and [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) for the CSS files. My site has an *index.html* page as well as other content pages. I created each each page in Notepad++, with each page having its own CSS file.

I'm having trouble with code that has one CSS file that maintains all headers and footer. And this main CSS file with name "global.css" is placed in the "main css" folder with file *index.html*. When I try to link the *global.css* file with other pages, it doesn't work. But it works with *index.html*... Other pages are in a separate folder named "pages". What should I do?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Games</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main css\global.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
</head>
```

Comment: as a tip: You should not uses spaces in folders when programming. I have always experienced problems with that. I don't know wether that is your problem, but it might be.

Comment: 1. Folder names should be without spaces. 2. you can go a directory up with .. So for example ../mydir/file.css

Comment: I remember having the same question when I just started out :) You have to "tell" your html page the folder where css file is in. For example, if you have main website folder where there are index.html and global.css and folder called "pages", than to link global.css file to any html file in "pages" folder you have to either write "/websiteFolder/global.css", or "../global.css"  Two dots goes one folder back.

Comment: not working..What if i have more sub directories.mean my pages folder contain more folders every page have its own folder. will i have to increase the no of dots(...../global.css).

Answer (score 3):

You can use double dot and forward slash, "**../**", to go one folder out. Also as mentioned in the comments, do not use spaces in the folder names. Use underscores, "_", instead.

For example, your inner pages which are in another folder will have the style page URL like below (please remove the spaces from the folder names):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../main_css/global.css">
```

Comment: not working.i remove the spaces and also add the "dots" but not working.What if i have more sub directories.mean my pages folder contain more folders.every page have its own folder (pages/games/game.html). will i have to increase the no of dots(...../global.css).

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your folder tree?

Comment: i add the captured image below in answer....checj the link"enter image description",,,,thank sir

Answer (score 0):

You could also change your HTML file in PHP and just link them with your index... For example, you got an index file where all your CSS links are included like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFolder/global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFolder/game.css" />
```

And just link all your files with your index like this:

```
<li><a href="index.php?page=htmlFile">htmlFile</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=anotherFile">anotherFile</a></li>
```